# How to find line's coefficients which pass for two 2D points?

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation \eqref{1} represents all the lines in the plane.

$$ax + by + c = 0\tag{1}\label{1}$$

**Objective:** Given the wanted line passes by $(x_0, \ y_0)$ and $(x_1, \ y_1)$, I want to get the coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$.

A way to find them is by "solving" the linear system \eqref{2}, which is in fact impossible cause there's one missing equation.

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_0 & y_0 & 1 \\ x_1 & y_1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\tag{2}\label{2}$$

The third equation comes from scaling the coefficients. Example: these two equations represents the same line

$$2x + y + 1 = 0$$
$$4x + 2y + 2 = 0$$

I thought about setting a constraint like \eqref{3}, but my problem is not linear anymore.

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1\label{3}\tag{3}$$

Even if I find a solution $(a_0, b_0, c_0)$, then $(-a_0, -b_0, -c_0)$ is also a solution, due to quadratic nature of \eqref{3}.

**Question:** How to find these coefficients?

Comment: Assumimg $b\ne 0$, divide the whole equation by $b$ to get $\dfrac{a}{b}x+y+\dfrac{c}{b}=0$ and substitute $\dfrac{a}{b}=\beta$ and $\dfrac{c}{b}=\lambda$. Then, you have an equation $\beta x+y+\lambda =0$, which has only two coeffcients, which can be determined by knowing two points lying on the sought line.

Comment: @YNK The problem of this approach is the supposition, which loses generality. This solution is useful only for vertical lines, which can not be true.

Comment: If you do not like the method I described in my previous comment, you can assume that $c$ is known and write
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_0 & y_0 \\x_1 & y_1 \\\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a \\b \\\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} -c \\-c \\\end{bmatrix}$$
and solve it to express $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$. By the way, the equation you get from the first method is not that of a vertical line always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the line $L$ joining the two given points $Q(x_0,y_0)$ and $R(x_1,y_1)$ is $\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$.  Suppose $P(x,y)$ is a point on the line $L$, then $m_{PQ}=m_{QR}$ and hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\quad  & \frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0} \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad &\left(y_1-y_0\right) x-x_0\left(y_1-y_0\right)-\left(x_1-x_0\right) y +y_0\left(x_1-x_0\right)=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad &\left(y_1-y_0\right) x+\left(x_0-x_1\right) y+\left(y_0 x_1-x_0 y_1\right)=0 \\
&\end{aligned}
$$
which is the equation of $L$.

By comparing, we may simply choose
$$
a=y_1-y_0, \quad  b=x_0-x_1 \text { and } \quad  c= y_0 x_1-x_0 y_1
$$

Answer (score 0):

The constraint \eqref{3} is not valid once the line with $(a, b, c) = (0, 0, 1)$ doesn't exist.

The scaling problem is solved by relating only $a$ and $b$:

$$a^2 + b^2 = 1$$

By changing the variables to $a = \cos \theta$ and $b = \sin \theta$

$$x_0 \cos \theta + y_0 \sin \theta + c = 0 \label{4}\tag{4}$$
$$x_1 \cos \theta + y_1 \sin \theta + c = 0 \label{5}\tag{5}$$

Do  $\left[x_1\cdot \eqref{4} - x_0\cdot \eqref{5}\right]$ to get \eqref{6}

$$c(x_1-x_0) = (x_0y_1 - x_1y_0) \cdot \sin \theta \tag{6}\label{6}$$

Do  $\left[y_1\cdot \eqref{4} - y_0\cdot \eqref{5}\right]$ to get \eqref{7}

$$c(y_1-y_0) = (x_1y_0 - x_0y_1) \cdot \cos \theta \tag{7}\label{7}$$

Do $\eqref{6}^2 + \eqref{7}^2$ to get

$$c^2 \left(\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2+\left(y_1-y_0\right)^2\right) = \left(x_0y_1 - x_1y_0\right)^2$$

It's expected that two points are not the same, and then we can divide:

$$c = \dfrac{\pm \left|x_0y_1 - x_1y_0\right|}{\sqrt{\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2+\left(y_1-y_0\right)^2}}$$

The actual value of $c$ doesn't matter, therefore we can set:

$$c = \dfrac{\left|x_0y_1 - x_1y_0\right|}{\sqrt{\left(x_1-x_0\right)^2+\left(y_1-y_0\right)^2}}$$

To finally find the value of $\theta$, get \eqref{4} and set

$$\cos \alpha = \dfrac{x_0}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \sin \alpha = \dfrac{y_0}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}}$$

$$\cos \alpha \cos \theta + \sin \alpha \sin \theta + \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}} = 0$$
$$\cos \left(\theta - \alpha\right) + \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}} = 0$$
$$\theta = \alpha + \arccos \left(\dfrac{-c}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}}\right)$$